# Detect sitecore media browser OK button click using javascript and get confirmation result

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sitecore

Is there a way to detect a Sitecore media browser "OK" button click from within an ascx user control using javascript and retrieve the id of a media item selected? I am first launching the media browser from my ascx control as follows:

```
<A class="scChromeCommand" title="Open Media Browser" onclick="GetMediaItem();" href="#"><IMG alt="Open Media Browser" src="http://localhost:2438/temp/IconCache/applications/16x16/photo_scenery.png" width="16" height="16" /></A>

function GetMediaItem() {
        Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.postRequest('example:MediaBrowser(id=<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString() %>)', null, false);        
    }
```

At the moment, when the link is clicked, the media browser is opened in a modal dialog and we can select an item from the browser. My custom "MediaBrowser" class, which inherits the Sitecore Command class, is executed and retrieves the dialog postback results after the "OK" button is clicked.

However, although i can get the item id in the "MediaBrowser" class after it has executed after clicking the "OK" button, i don't know how i can use the item id on my ascx control (where the media browser was opened from). Any idea how i can achieve this using javascript?